# iPod Nano battery loses charge when it's cold

Tags: ipod, battery

My fourth-gen iPod Nano has very recently started to completely lose its charge when I'm outdoors (currently it's a bit colder here, about 10°C / 50°F).

Indoors, or when it's warmer, it still manages a relatively reasonable music playback time of about 10 hrs. Is there anything I can do except contact Apple about a battery replacement? (The iPod is no longer under warranty and I want to avoid the 59 currency unit fee.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temperature you describe is not cold enough to affect battery functions too much. It’s within the operating temperatures and it shouldn’t happen. Take a look at the temperature charts in the [Apple iPod Battery](http://www.apple.com/batteries/ipods.html) page and if it doesn’t perform as expected, contact them immediately.

**UPDATE**: If the iPod is not under warranty, you’re pretty much “hosed”, however, you can attempt a manual battery replacement. [This google query](http://www.google.es/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=replace+ipod+nano+battery&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=eL-8TMD0D8Oa4Ab3s-3_Dg) is a good starting point.